# Adding to a php array

Tags: php, arrays, push

I am using Woocommerce for a shopping cart, and I have a basic php question. Below is the template code that generates a class for a list item within a loop:

```
$classes = array();
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes[] = 'first';
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes[] = 'last';
?>
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

I want to delete the conditional statements, and replace it with a class of 'mix'. So every single list item should have a class of mix, forget about the first and last. I would assume this would work, but it does not:

```
$classes = array();
 $classes[] = 'mix'; ?>
 <li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I'm not sure, but it looks like you're never closing the php code after `'mix';` with an ending tag: `?>`.

Comment: no errors, just typed it in incorrectly. I fixed it above

Comment: If the above code with first/last works, then what you posted below should work as well. Are you getting any errors? Did you inspect the element to see if there is any inline PHP error in the <li> tag?

Comment: it is working, it was just hidden due to js issues. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: I don't know how post_class works. maybe you need an echo? `<li <?php echo post_class( $classes ); ?>>`